# Documentation? and is $nin in mongodb Aggregation or not?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For the 4.6 mongo aggregation docs on operator expressions, $in is mentioned and $not is mentioned but $nin is not mentioned.
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#agg-quick-ref-operator-expressions

$nin is explained for find and update in the docs. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

On jira for those logged in with access solutions are given using $nin with aggregation examples. 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9030?focusedCommentId=294125&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-294125

But is $nin a valid operation, because it is not in the docs.
Or as an alternative will $in and $not, combined return documents with $nin functionality?

example:

```
db.collection("collection).aggregate([
{
  $match {
    'fieldname': {$nin: ['10', '20','2']}
  }
}
])
```

alternative example,

```
db.collection("collection).aggregate([
{
  $project: {
    "store location" : "$location",
    "has bananas" : { $in: [ "bananas", "$in_stock" ] }
  }
}
{
  $match: { "has bananas": 0 }
}
])
```

wow, when I was writing the example I think I figured it out. 
If I want $nin I should just match where $in returns false.

Hopefully, there is still reason to post the question as it provided me with confusion and may have confused others.
regards, Michael Dimmitt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection("collection).aggregate([
{
  $project: {
    "store location" : "$location",
    "has bananas" : { $in: [ "bananas", "$in_stock" ] }
  }
}
{
  $match: { "has bananas": 0 }
}
])
```

wow, when I was writing the example I think I figured it out.

If I want $nin I should just match where $in returns false.

Hopefully, there is still reason to post the question as it provided me with confusion and may have confused others.

If this solution is incorrect and can be proven I will mark the correct solution as the answer.
regards, Michael Dimmitt
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/in/

Comment: I do not understand how they obtain those that are not within the arrangement, could you explain to me? if it's not much of a hassle of course, I'm having a similar problem.